# How do I cycle through images with a single button?

Tags: javascript, image, cycle

I have just started coding javascript in notepad++ at a GCSE level.
One of my tasks in my Assessment is to make traffic lights change colour, one image for each button click. 
I have got as far as Making the Red light change to a Red-Yellow light. However, I am unable to go further with this.
My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function lewis() {
    document.getElementById("pic").src="Red-Yellow.png"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="lewis()">
Change Lights</button>
<img src="Red.png" alt="Red" id="pic" style="width:250px;height:600px;">
</body>
</html>
```

This is the height of my ability as I have just started.
*Any* help would be appreciated, many thanks,
Lewis

(I will continue to do research alongside this question)

Comment: You realize java isn't the same thing as javascript, right?

Comment: add an if statement to check the current value, or add them in an array, so you can go to nextIndex

Comment: Some ways that spring to my mind: - use an index and increment it on each button press - use some if-statement to check the image name and decide on the next image - replace the button or at least the onclick event when clicked.

Comment: It's it not Neil? Never realised...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't tested but i guess you want something like that.

```
function lewis() {
        var current_image = document.getElementById("pic").src;
        if(current_image == "Red.png"){
            document.getElementById("pic").src = "Red-Yellow.png";
        }else if(current_image == "Red-Yellow.png"){
            document.getElementById("pic").src = "Red-Green.png";
        }else if(current_image == "Red-Green.png"){
            document.getElementById("pic").src = "last-color.png";
        }else if(current_image == "last-color.png"){
            document.getElementById("pic").src = "Red.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try next lesson <3

Comment: i'm not sure yet, literally about to try, will keep you in the loop <3

Comment: Right, this is irritating, I _tried_ but was being stubborn. I opened it with chrome and tried opening the dev tools and it said nothing was wrong. I have 30 mins left of this lesson and will attempt to fix the problem before then. thankyou for your help. :)

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I quickly realized that needed to put the image location in front of the '.png' file. It is complete and fully functional now, thankyou so much :D

Comment: if this answer solved your problem you can accept it as solution or can give vote